# Is it possible to get a XYY genotype by the first meiotic non-disjunction?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

I have read that the cause of XYY-Syndrome is a non-disjuction in the secondary non-disjunction in the meiosis. I was woundering if it is possible to get the XYY-Syndrom by the first meiotic non-disjunction? I would assume yes, since you would get XX and YY Gametes.